# How to map `""` to `ysiw"` from surround.vim?

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-vim-surround

I would like to map `""` to `ysiw"` from surround.vim to reduce number of keystrokes needed to surround a word with double quotes.

I have tried `:noremap "" ysiw"`, however it does not work. Any ideas what could I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regular map for a normal mode `nmap`:

```
nmap "" ysiw"
```

`noremap` is for several modes and it uses default meaning of the commands you provide on the right side, `nore` means "no remap".